# Loop through variable 2 elements at a time in bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have a bash variable which is a white-space separated list of strings and would like a loop that iterates 2 elements at a time from that list. I've made sure the length of the list is divisible by 2. So I want something like:

```
x="a bb cccc d"
while read first second; do
    echo "($first,$second)"
done <<< $x
```

output should be:

```
(a,bb)
(cccc,d)
```

currently the above yields:

```
(a,bb cccc d)
```

**Note:** I need the assignment of `$first` and `$second` in my loop. `echo` was put in as a placeholder.
I'm looking for an efficient answer (preferably without a counter).

Comment: `<<< "$x"` is sufficient, no need to capture the output of `echo` with a command substitution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the values, you could do something like this:

```
$ x="one two buckle myShoe"
$ xargs -n 2 printf "(%s,%s)\n" <<<$x
(one,two)
(buckle,myShoe)
```

I assume that you really want to assign the values to shell variables, though, and that the body of your anticipated loop is more complicated than a simple formated print. In fact, since `printf` automatically repeats the format until its arguments are exhausted, `xargs` in the above example was unnecessary; it could have just been:

```
printf "(%s,%s)\n" $x
```

Unfortunately, `xargs` is not a built-in, so you can't `xargs` an arbitrary bash pipeline. Nor can you just define a shell function and give `xargs` its name. You can, however, `xargs` a bash subshell, which provides a very general solution:

```
# Shell function which takes two arguments
doit() {
  echo "Number of arguments: $#"
  echo "First argument: $1"
  echo "Second argument: $2"
}
# Make the function visible to subshells
export -f doit

x="one two buckle myShoe"
xargs -n2 bash -c 'doit "$@"' _ <<<$x
```

Finally, as per a discussion in comments, you can use either `printf` or `xargs` (but probably `printf` is more efficient, since it is a builtin) to reorganize the list into pairs, and then feed that into a `while read` loop:

```
printf "%s %s\n" $x |
while read -r first second; do
  echo "($first,$second)"
done
```

Comment: This gave me this idea: `while read ab; do read a b <<< "$ab"; echo "($a,$b)"; done <<< "$(xargs -n 2 <<< "$x")";`. Not sure how elegant it is..

Comment: @isthisthat: elegance is in the eye of the beholder :) But two reads is inelegant imho: I'd use: `xargs -n2 <<<$x | while read -r a b; do (something with $a and $b); done`. (If you just want formatted output, though, printf is the winner.)

Comment: awesome!! that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

### Using `shift` and `$1`, `$2`, etc.

- You can use `set -- $x` to assign each part of `x` to the bash variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.
- You can use `shift <n>` to shift the numbered variables down by `n`. (I.e. `shift 2` moves the value of `$3` to `$1`, and `$4` to `$2`, etc.)

#### Example

```
x="a bb cccc d"

set -- $x
while [ ! -z "$1" ]  # while $1 is not empty
do
  # do whatever you want here with $1 and $2. you can take more
  # than two at a time by calling shift with a higher argument
  # (and use $1, $2, and $3).

  echo "($1,$2)"
  shift 2
done
```

This prints:

```
(a,bb)
(cccc,d)
```

#### If you need the command line arguments

Save them to a temporary variable:

```
ARGS=( "$@" )      # save the command line args
set -- $x

...

set -- "${ARGS[@]}"    # restore them back
```

Comment: @isthisthat I feel like this has the elegance you were looking for. :) I had to solve this myself just today and stumbled upon this bash feature.

Comment: very elegant solution indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I would declare your variable like this :

```
x="a b c d"
A=($x)
```

And then

```
$ for ((i=0; i<${#A[*]}; i=i+2)); do echo "("${A[$i]},${A[$i+1]}")"; done
(a,b)
(c,d)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Given that my variable is already defined as above, how would you cast it to an array?

Comment: You can do this : `A=($x)`

Comment: great answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `read` to read specific # of characters:

```
while read -n4 first second; do echo "($first,$second)"; done <<< "$x"
(a,b)
(c,d)
```

**EDIT:** For generic solution use awk:

```
x="aa bb cccc de"
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) printf "(%s,%s)\n", $i, $(i+1) }' <<< "$x"
(aa,bb)
(cccc,de)
```

Comment: But what I see is that with `-n4` you indicate that you have to read `4` exact chars. If the input is for example `x="aa bb cc dd"` it would break. (Reference in bash builtins http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins)

Comment: Yes that's right, answer was for single char fields like OP had. I will see if I can make it generic.

Comment: yup. My use-case is generic, that is, `a b c d` could be of arbitrary length, only delimited by space (or newline, etc). Thanks!